# if variable is missed

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

have adynamic vars = names defined by users

```
var Human = "Mohamed"
var Animal = "Cat"
var Bird = "Dove"
var Amphibians = "Frog"
```

now if user put 1st three vars without the 4th variable like

```
var human = "mohamed"
var animal = "cat"
var bird = "Dove"
```

if variable Amphiblians is missed do something

Answer (score 0):

No, if you attempted to use `Amphibians` it would throw an exception as the variable has not been defined.

If you want to set a default value for `Amphibians` if it's not defined then you can do

```
if (typeof Amphibians === 'undefined') {
    var Amphibians = '';
}
```